# How to suppress the Efficiency cores on Apple Silicon?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

I work on a mathematical modeller, which is licensed to ISVs as a library to use in their applications. It is *not* an application in itself: its test harness is a command-line program.

We measure its performance rather carefully with each build. The idea is to catch code changes that slow things down, and try to revise them to avoid that. We refuse to make things slower without a good reason, and over time this has improved performance. On machines where all the CPU cores have similar performance, this works quite well.

However, on Apple Silicon Macs, the time taken to run test cases that use multiple threads varies widely. Threads are being assigned to Performance or Efficiency cores almost at random. We've attempted to apply Apple's [task priority guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheTaskLevel.html) but found that setting the threads to user-initiated has almost no effect.

Apple does not provide public APIs for pinning threads to cores. I understand their reasoning in this, but I'm dealing with a case that isn't addressed by their focus on the user interaction experience. I'm trying to discover the maximum performance *potential* of code and compare it with different code.

We're looking into subtler forms of thread management, but there's an obvious form that's completely unsubtle: is it possible to turn off the Efficiency cores at boot time, or at any other point before launching the test harness?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can disable any CPU via the `cpumask` boot-arg. In practice, however, you cannot disable the boot CPU, and that happens to be an E-core on Apple Silicon.

The closest thing to what you're looking for are probably the `enable_skstb` and `enable_skstsct` boot-args, which do allow pinning of threads and tasks to clusters and individual CPUs, **however**: they are only present in `DEVELOPMENT` and `DEBUG` configs. So you'll have to grab a [Kernel Debug Kit](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Kernel%20Debug%20Kit), build a development kernelcache, and then boot from that with the mentioned boot-args.
And then you can use sysctls such as `kern.sched_task_set_cluster_type` to bind yourself to the P cluster. There's [a test file in the XNU source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/xnu-8796.101.5/tools/tests/zero-to-n/zero-to-n.c#L862-L876) where Apple does this:

```c
static int
set_recommended_cluster(char cluster_char)
{
    char buff[4];
    buff[1] = '\0';

    buff[0] = cluster_char;

    int ret = sysctlbyname("kern.sched_task_set_cluster_type", NULL, NULL, buff, 1);
    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("kern.sched_task_set_cluster_type");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

They call it with the lowercase letter `'p'` as argument.